Flutter DataTables align cell text to left
I just found DataTables and it helps my app tremendously. However, given the example from the documentation
how can I make the text in the cells align to the left. The separator line starts ~20 pixels left of the text. I would like both Text and line be aligned vertically so I do not lose any space (or minimal offset).
Just adding textAlign: TextAlign.left to the Text item in the cell does not do the trick.
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DataTable(
      columns: const <DataColumn>[
        DataColumn(
          label: Expanded(
            child: Text(
              'Name',
              style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        DataColumn(
          label: Expanded(
            child: Text(
              'Age',
              style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        DataColumn(
          label: Expanded(
            child: Text(
              'Role',
              style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
      rows: const <DataRow>[
        DataRow(
          cells: <DataCell>[
            DataCell(Text('Sarah')),
            DataCell(Text('19')),
            DataCell(Text('Student')),
          ],
        ),
        DataRow(
          cells: <DataCell>[
            DataCell(Text('Janine')),
            DataCell(Text('43')),
            DataCell(Text('Professor')),
          ],
        ),
        DataRow(
          cells: <DataCell>[
            DataCell(Text('William')),
            DataCell(Text('27')),
            DataCell(Text('Associate Professor')),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }



Please [edit] your question to include the code you have already tried.
Also, it would help to add some images.

Code added, it is copy pasted from the example that I linked.
